# type 'ExpandIterable<InterfaceType, MethodElement>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<MethodElementImpl>' of 'iterable'

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, dio, build-runner

I want to create a api services using dio and build_runner. But when I run `flutter pub run build_runner` this command on terminal I got this error

> [SEVERE] retrofit_generator:retrofit on
> lib/web_services/api_services.dart:
>
> type 'ExpandIterable<InterfaceType, MethodElement>' is not a subtype
> of type 'Iterable' of 'iterable'

This is my api services code.

```
part 'api_services.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: Preferences.hrmsAPI)
abstract class RestClient {
  factory RestClient(Dio dio) = _RestClient;

  @FormUrlEncoded()
  @GET('config')
  Future<WrappedResponse> config();

  @FormUrlEncoded()
  @GET('profile')
  Future<WrappedResponse> profile(@Header('Authorization') String token);
}
```

Comment: It seems like a error in the package itself , you should head to the repo and raise an issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reported Issue : https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/issues/345

Temp fix:

```
retrofit_generator:
git:
  url: https://github.com/Chimerapps/retrofit.dart.git
  ref: 9f90296751984b359937c38563da5b19db5550f5
  path: generator
```

**UPDATE**

As the Jun 4, 2021 we get new package update, that fix the problem.

```
retrofit_generator 2.0.0+1
```